# Install CXF in Jboss5.0

Tags: jboss, installation, cxf, jbossws

Today i tried to install Apache CXF in JBOSS-WS.

I followed the instructions from https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-Installation.
I am using jbossws-cxf-4.0.0.GA . I am getting an exception when i try to install.

> D:\jboss-5.0.1.GA\jbossws-cxf-bin-dist>ant
>   -Djboss.server.instance=default deplo y-jboss500 Buildfile: build.xml
>
> BUILD FAILED Target "deploy-jboss500" does not exist in the project
>   "JBossWS-CXF".

The following file is my ant.properties file

```
#
# A sample ant properties file
#

# Optional JBoss Home
jboss500.home=D:\jboss-5.0.1.GA
jboss700.home=@jboss700.home@
jboss701.home=@jboss701.home@
jboss702.home=@jboss702.home@
jboss710.home=@jboss710.home@

# The JBoss server under test. This can be [jboss700|jboss701|jboss702|jboss710]
jbossws.integration.target=jboss500

# The JBoss settings
jboss.bind.address=localhost

# JBoss Management console authentication (AS 7.1.x)
jbossws.deployer.authentication.username=admin
jbossws.deployer.authentication.password=admin

# JBoss JMX invoker authentication (AS 7.0.x)
#jmx.authentication.username=admin
#jmx.authentication.password=admin

# Java Compiler options
javac.debug=yes
javac.deprecation=no
javac.fail.onerror=yes
javac.verbose=no
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're trying to use the latest version of JBossWS that dropped support for JBoss AS 5.

See https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-SupportedTargetContainers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes now i moved to Jboss6.0.